# Hadoop 2 node cluster UI showing 1 live Node

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, bigdata

I am trying to configure Hadoop 2.7  2-node cluster.When i start hadoop 
using start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh.All services on master and slave start perfectly.

```
Here is my jps command on  my master:
23913 Jps
22140 SecondaryNameNode
22316 ResourceManager
22457 NodeManager
21916 DataNode
21777 NameNode

Here is my jps command on  my slave:
17223 Jps
14225 DataNode
14363 NodeManager
```

But if i see Hadoop cluster UI it shows only 1 live data node.

```
Here is the dfs admin report : /bin/hdfs dfsadmin -report
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 192.168.1.104:50010 (nn1.cluster.com)
Hostname: nn1.cluster.com
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 401224601600 (373.67 GB)
DFS Used: 237568 (232 KB)
Non DFS Used: 48905121792 (45.55 GB)
DFS Remaining: 352319242240 (328.12 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 87.81%
```

I am able to ssh on all machines.

```
Here is the sample of name node logs(i.p = 192.168.1.104) : 
2016-07-12 01:17:34,293 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* processReport: from storage DS-d9ed40cf-bd5d-4033-a6ca-14fb4a8c3587 node DatanodeRegistration(192.168.1.104:50010, datanodeUuid=b702b518-5daa-4fa1-8e69-e4d620a72470, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-e86d0353-9f33-495b-88fa-16035abd3672;nsid=616310490;c=0), blocks: 24, hasStaleStorage: false, processing time: 0 msecs
2016-07-12 01:17:35,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* registerDatanode: from DatanodeRegistration(192.168.1.104:50010, datanodeUuid=37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-e86d0353-9f33-495b-88fa-16035abd3672;nsid=616310490;c=0) storage 37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe
2016-07-12 01:17:35,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: BLOCK* registerDatanode: 192.168.1.104:50010
2016-07-12 01:17:35,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Removing a node: /default-rack/192.168.1.104:50010
2016-07-12 01:17:35,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeDescriptor: Number of failed storage changes from 0 to 0
2016-07-12 01:17:35,502 INFO org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/192.168.1.104:50010
2016-07-12 01:17:35,504 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeDescriptor: Number of failed storage changes from 0 to 0
2016-07-12 01:17:35,504 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeDescriptor: Adding new storage ID DS-495b6b0e-f1fc-407c-bb9f-6c314c2fdaec for DN 192.168.1.104:50010

here is the sample datanode logs (i.p = 192.168.1.104): 
2016-07-12 02:02:12,044 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeCommand action : DNA_REGISTER from nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 with active state
2016-07-12 02:02:12,045 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid b702b518-5daa-4fa1-8e69-e4d620a72470) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2016-07-12 02:02:12,047 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid b702b518-5daa-4fa1-8e69-e4d620a72470) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 successfully registered with NN
2016-07-12 02:02:12,050 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0x236119eb3082,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 24 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 0 msec to generate and 1 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2016-07-12 02:02:12,050 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934
2016-07-12 02:02:15,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeCommand action : DNA_REGISTER from nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 with active state
2016-07-12 02:02:15,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid b702b518-5daa-4fa1-8e69-e4d620a72470) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2016-07-12 02:02:15,056 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid b702b518-5daa-4fa1-8e69-e4d620a72470) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 successfully registered with NN
2016-07-12 02:02:15,061 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0x2361cd4be40d,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 24 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 0 msec to generate and 2 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2016-07-12 02:02:15,061 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934

Here is the sample of 2nd datanode logs(ip :192.168.35.128)
2016-07-12 11:45:07,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeCommand action : DNA_REGISTER from nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 with active state
2016-07-12 11:45:07,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid 37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2016-07-12 11:45:07,355 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid 37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 successfully registered with NN
2016-07-12 11:45:07,364 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0xb0de42ec7c,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 0 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 0 msec to generate and 4 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2016-07-12 11:45:07,364 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934
2016-07-12 11:45:10,360 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeCommand action : DNA_REGISTER from nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 with active state
2016-07-12 11:45:10,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid 37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2016-07-12 11:45:10,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid 37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 successfully registered with NN
2016-07-12 11:45:10,377 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0xb191ea9cb9,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 0 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 0 msec to generate and 3 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2016-07-12 11:45:10,377 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934
2016-07-12 11:45:13,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeCommand action : DNA_REGISTER from nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 with active state
2016-07-12 11:45:13,380 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid 37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2016-07-12 11:45:13,385 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934 (Datanode Uuid 37038a9f-23ac-42e2-abea-bdf356aaefbe) service to nn1.cluster.com/192.168.1.104:8020 successfully registered with NN
2016-07-12 11:45:13,395 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0xb245b893c4,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 0 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 0 msec to generate and 5 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2016-07-12 11:45:13,396 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-1235752202-192.168.1.104-1468159707934
```

Why is this happening? Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Did you Check the hadoop namenode and datanode logs ?

Comment: I have checked the name node and datanode logs . I didnt't find any kind of error in both the logs. I have tried reformatting name node and manually deleting datanode directory and starting the service again but still in UI live node shows 1 deadnode shows 0 .

Comment: @nath - I have added sample namenode and datanode logs in the question itself.Is there something i am missing ?

Comment: it seems that namenode & datanode logs are from same m/c where namenode and datanode are setup, is it correct  ?

Comment: I have Ubuntu machine and have installed single virtual setup in ubuntu.
So have two i/ps: one for Ubuntu and other for virtual setup
So the ubuntu machine acts as namenode and datanode and virtual setup acts as a datanode.

Comment: @nath - The logs for both the datanode were similar so i have added sample datanode logs for Ubuntu machine.should i add the sample logs for other datanode ?

Comment: @B.G - have you tried starting cluster by `start-all.sh`?

Comment: @BigDataLearner - Yes  i  have started cluster by running start-all.sh

Comment: do you have entry for remote datanode's hostname or ip in `slaves` file?

Comment: @BigDataLearner Sorry for replying so late.got stuck in some other deadlines work .Finally  posted  the answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solution. The issue was in namenode Ipaddress. i had considered ipaddress from wlan0 interface which keeps 
on changing.Since I have installed VMware workstation so  considered the Ipaddress 
from vmnet interface which was static ipaddress and after changing Live node shows 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Got The Solution. If the Slave Nodes/Data Nodes are alive individually and in the report if it is not showing it on the report hadoop dfsadmin - report...then there is the problem with the communication. The communication from data node to the master is not available. Technically speaking there is the issue in the firewall. the Fire wall in the master node is blocking the communication.

" We have to stop the firewall connection in the master" / Allow the specific Ip to access the master"

to stop Firewall in CentOs do the below Command in CentOs

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```